# MySQL : Selecting the rows with the highest group by count

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table with records that are updated every minute with a decimal value (10,2). To ignore measure errors I want to have the number that has been inserted the most.
Therefor I tried:

```sql
SELECT date_time,max(sensor1),count(ID)
FROM `weigh_data
group by day(date_time),sensor1
```

This way I get the number of records

```
Datetime              sensor1    count(ID)
2020-03-19 11:49:12   33.22      3
2020-03-19 11:37:47   33.36      10
2020-03-20 07:32:02   32.54      489
2020-03-20 00:00:43   32.56      891
2020-03-20 14:20:51   32.67      5
2020-03-21 07:54:16   32.50      1
2020-03-21 00:00:58   32.54      1373
2020-03-21 01:15:16   32.56      9
2020-03-22 08:35:12   32.52      2
2020-03-22 00:00:40   32.54      575
2020-03-22 06:50:54   32.58      1
```

What I actually want is for each day one row which has the highest count(ID)

Anyone can help me out on this?

Comment: What version of mysql

Comment: Its running on vers ion 8.0 .

Answer (score 1):

With newer MySQL (8.0 and later) you can use the [`RANK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank) window function to rank the rows according to the count.

Note that this will return all "ties" which means if there are 100 readings of X and 100 readings of Y (and 100 is the max), both X and Y will be returned.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    DATE(date_time), sensor1,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(date_time) ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk
  FROM `weigh_data` GROUP BY DATE(date_time), sensor1
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rnk=1
```

If you just want to pick one (non deterministic) of the ties, you can instead use [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) in place of `RANK`

[A DBfiddle to test with.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2161a5f1c14c4119877f827555b5e128)

Comment: This solution worked flawless and fast . Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on a correlated subquery, that works in all versions of MySQL:

```
select w.*
from weigh_data w
where w.datetime = (
    select w1.datetime 
    from weigh_data w1
    where w1.datetime >= date(w.datetime) and w1.datetime < date(w.datetime) + interval 1 day
    order by sensor1 desc
    limit 1
)
```

Just like the window function solution using `rank()`, this allows top ties.

For performance, you want an index on `(datetime, sensor1)`.