# Mysql : Select the value that has changed from it's previous (grouped_by) value

Tags: mysql, group-by

i would like to extend the question i had asked here :
[MySQL : Selecting the rows with the highest group by count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60798346/mysql-selecting-the-rows-with-the-highest-group-by-count)

this was answered perfectly, but it turns out i would like to extend the functionality of the
query , without luck so far.

My data still looks like this , grouped by sensor values. i asked to have the highest count every day, which as i said was solved in the other q.

```
    Datetime              sensor1    count(ID)
2020-03-19 11:49:12   33.22      3
2020-03-19 11:37:47   33.36      10
2020-03-20 07:32:02   32.54      489
2020-03-20 00:00:43   32.56      891
2020-03-20 14:20:51   32.67      5
2020-03-21 07:54:16   32.50      1
2020-03-21 00:00:58   32.54      1373
2020-03-21 01:15:16   32.56      9
2020-03-22 08:35:12   32.52      2
2020-03-22 00:00:40   32.54      575
2020-03-22 06:50:54   32.58      1
```

And with this query i get a perfect result :

```
 WITH cte AS 
( SELECT DATE(date_time) as date_time, sensor1, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(date_time) 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk FROM `weigh_data` GROUP BY DATE(date_time), sensor1 ) 
SELECT * FROM cte as a WHERE rnk=1
```

result :

```
2020-03-20  32.56  
2020-03-21  32.54 *
2020-03-22  32.54
2020-03-23  31.92 *
2020-03-24  31.92
2020-03-25  31.92
2020-03-26  31.28 *
```

Now i would like to have the result only showing the rows where i put an asterix. The rows that changed
from the previous one. I can manage this in PHP, but it would be more effecient to have it directly from the query result. Would this be possible ?
I know how to select changes in result data, but not when it's grouped like this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT DATE(date_time) as date_time, 
                 sensor1, 
                 RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(date_time) ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk 
          FROM `weigh_data` 
          GROUP BY DATE(date_time), sensor1 ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT date_time, 
                 sensor1, 
                 LAG(sensor1) OVER (ORDER BY date_time) sensor2
          FROM cte1 
          WHERE rnk = 1 )
SELECT date_time, 
       sensor1
FROM cte2
WHERE sensor1 != sensor2 
   OR sensor2 IS NULL;
```